# Pyqt treeview with checkboxes

Tags: python, checkbox, treeview, pyqt

I'm new to PyQt and I'm trying to do some specyfic stuff but without luck :(
I'm trying to create a expandable tree of items (treeview) with pyqt, but I want, that on the left of each name there will be a non-exclusive checkbox.

I found some codes but for now the best result was tree with only checkboxes :(

Does somebody have some minimal example how to achive this effect?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Example of what you have tried, research and resources you have used thus far to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's ItemViews draw checkboxes next to the text, if the ItemIsUserCheckable flag is set for the item in the model. If you write your own model you must implement QAbstractItemModel::flags, if you use QTreeWidget you can set the flags for each QTreeWidgetItem.